# WebAPI2 OData exception returning XML after applying $select

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have a controller that applies `ODataQueryOptions` and returns a non-generic `IQueryable`. This works fine for `text/html` but when requesting `application/xml` or `text/xml` with a `$select` this error is thrown:

> The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for
>   content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'.
>
> Type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[[System.Web.Http.OData.Query.Expressions.SelectExpandBinder+SelectSome`1[[Data2.fn_GetStuff_Result,
>   Data2, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]],
>   System.Web.Http.OData, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]' with data contract name
>   'ArrayOfSelectExpandBinder.SelectSomeOffn_GetStuff_Resultzy_SQjfTr:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Web.Http.OData.Query.Expressions'
>   is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any
>   types not known statically to the list of known types - for example,
>   by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the
>   list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.

WebApiConfig.Register method:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(
    new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html")); 
modelBuilder.EntitySet<Data2.fn_GetStuff_Result>("Stuff");
```

This works fine from the browser and returns JSON formatted result. Changing the Accept header to `application/xml` or `text/xml` throws the above exception. If the `$select` is removed `application/xml` will return `application/json` result.

ORM is EF6 and the type is mapped from a table valued function from SQL Server.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(ODataQueryOptions<Data2.fn_GetStuff_Result> options)

// get Skip and Top from the options

var db = new Data2.MyEntities(); 
var query = db.fn_GetStuff(skip, take).AsQueryable();

// TODO - parse the request uri and strip out $skip and $top as these have already been applied through the server function 
// Applying them again will not return the correct results 
var newUri = new Uri("http://localhost/odata/Stuff()?$select=Id,Name"); 
var newRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, newUri); 
var newOptions = new ODataQueryOptions<Data2.fn_GetStuff_Result>(
    options.Context, newRequest);

var results = newOptions.ApplyTo(query); 
var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, results);

return response;
```

How can I get this to return XML or JSON when applying `$select` based on the Accept header?

This is the stack trace

```
<StackTrace>   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeAndVerifyType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean verifyKnownType, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithXsiTypeAtTopLevel(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle originalDeclaredTypeHandle, Type graphType)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObjectContent(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObject(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObjectHandleExceptions(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObjectHandleExceptions(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.WriteObject(XmlWriter writer, Object graph)
   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content)
   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.&lt;TraceBeginEndAsyncCore&gt;d__33.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.&lt;WriteBufferedResponseContentAsync&gt;d__14.MoveNext()</StackTrace></
```